# PHP - Class that can be instantiated only by another class

Tags: php, oop

Imagine this scenario:

```
class Page {}

class Book {
   private $pages = array();
   public function __construct() {}
   public function addPage($pagename) {
      array_push($this->pages, new Page($pagename));
   }
}
```

Is there anyway i can make sure only objects of my class Book can instantiate Page?
Like, if the programmer tries something like:

```
$page = new Page('pagename');
```

the script throws an exception?

Thanks

Comment: why? thats bad practice.

Comment: This one's actually related to python, but I think it applies very well: "We're all consenting adults here".

Comment: why is it a bad practice @Daniel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit contrived, but you could use this:

```
abstract class BookPart
{
    abstract protected function __construct();
}

class Page
    extends BookPart
{
    private $title;

    // php allows you to override the signature of constructors
    protected function __construct( $title )
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }
}

class Book
    extends BookPart
{
   private $pages = array();

   // php also allows you to override the visibility of constructors
   public function __construct()
   {
   }

   public function addPage( $pagename )
   {
      array_push( $this->pages, new Page( $pagename ) );
   }
}

$page = new Page( 'test will fail' ); // Will result in fatal error. Comment out to make scrip work 

$book = new Book();
$book->addPage( 'test will work' ); // Will work.

var_dump( $book );
```

Comment: yes, it is a bit contrived but does exactly what i was asking for. thank you very much

Comment: Clever! And it even doesn't raise E_STRICT level errors if enabled.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I see your point, but with the tools provided by the language, this is not possible.

One thing you could do, is require a Book object when constructing a Page:

```
class Page {
    public function __construct( Book $Book ) {}
}

class Book {
    public function addPage() {
        $this->pages[] = new Page( $this );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it kind of helps me. I'm going to have to accept @genesis answer, for obvious reasons

Comment: Why? I told you it was not possible as well, and provided an alternative solution :P

Answer (score 3):

I think that the most you can get, is to have `Page` demand `Book` as one of it's constructor arguments, and have it add page to this instance of Book. This way you never have `Page`s floating around, but they're always bound to some book (although it's still possible to have same `Page` in many `Book`s.

```
class Book {
  public function addPage($page) {
    if(is_a($page,'Page') {
      $this->pages->push($page);
    } else if (is_string($page)) {
      new Page($this,$page)
    } else {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException("Expected string or 'Page' - ".gettype($page)." was given instead");
    }
  }
}

class Page {
  public function __construct(Book $book, $pagename) {
    $book->addPage($this);
  }
}
```

That looks ugly though... :/

Answer (score 1):

No. In PHP, it's not possible. Even if it would be possible, developer could modify to his own needs and disable your exeption...

Comment: This is true of course, but then what is the point in expecting anything from your classes / interfaces at all? I think you generally expect other developers not to touch your library of classes if they want to use them, or simply not guarantee the expected outcome if they are gonna tamper with it. What's more; if you issue an update to your library, they'll have to modify them again, and again, and again, etc.